# How can I explain Cross Site Scripting in a non-technical way?

Tags: xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anybody explain XSS to an idiot?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/can-anybody-explain-xss-to-an-idiot)

I can reasonably explain Cross Site Scripting (XSS) in technical terms to other technically minded people or people familiar with web-dev/app-sec, however I need to explain XSS to people, usually management, that aren't technically orientated.

Can anyone create explain the concepts simply so that general users can understand?

Thanks!