# Could blocking script in the url prevent DOM XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript

On my site, if I were to block `<script>` from the url, could this prevent some cases of XSS? Any way someone could bypass that?

Comment: I think you have some misunderstandings here. I assume you mean to filter out the string `<script>` from the URL parameter strings, like a query parameter. Have you done any research into how to prevent XSS? You will find that blacklisting strings in a query parameter is not the recommended way to address this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anybody explain XSS?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/can-anybody-explain-xss)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be bypassed. First, many filters that attempt to remove `<script>` tags do so in a way that is easily defeated. For example, they may improperly handle input like `<scr<script>ipt>`.

But even when implemented "properly", that is not sufficient, because `<script>` tags are not required to execute Javascript on a page: event handlers, script URIs, and data URIs can be used as well (note that I am unsure about browser support for the latter two). See OWASP's [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) page for more information.

And in DOM-based XSS, you may not be worried about HTML at all, instead stuffing Javascript into an [execution sink](https://code.google.com/p/domxsswiki/wiki/ExecutionSinks).