# DOM based XSS using window.location.hash

Tags: xss

Target code:

```
if($(location.href.split("#")[1])) {
  var target = $('#'+location.href.split("#")[1]);
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top - 160 //offset height of header here too.
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
```

It uses from `location.href`, so I though about using an injection script like this:
`target-url.com/#"+alert(1)+""`, escaping the string and placing an alert(1) to trigger an alert in the page. If I edit the script using Chrome Dev tools, the script is successfully executed:

[image]

But when trying to inject this script in the URL, analyzing the browser console, I see a jQuery error:

`jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: %22+alert(1)+%22%22`.
It appears to fail because it's replacing `"` with `%22`. But I need to scape the string scope, since `location.href.split("#")[1]` returns a string, and I need to leave the string scope to run the script.

Is there a way to bypass this URL encoding or this scenario is not exploitable at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to bypass this URL encoding

No, modern browsers correctly URL encode this value, and that cannot be bypassed.

But that's not the only problem. There's actually no double-quoted string here which you could escape with `"` (nor a single-quoted one which you could escape with `'`).

There *was* a jQuery vulnerability in earlier version where `$('#<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>')` would lead to XSS, but that is fixed in recent versions.

`$('<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>')` still leads to XSS, but there is no way to get rid of the `#` (and the URL encoding would also still be in the way).

Given all of this, I would say that the code isn't vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @tim! So, can we say that `window.location.hash` is completely safe from XSS injections? Since it's not possible to get rid of `#`

Comment: @GGirotto I meant the `#` in `$('#'`, not from the URL. Nothings ever completely safe, but at least in your example, it would only be exploitable for users who use severely outdated browsers (which don't URL-encode), and even that only if the app uses an outdated jquery version. There are other situations where incorrectly using `location.hash` can lead to DOM XSS (see eg the last example [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/219870/8754))